# can system-config-printer clear 'low on ink' status (Printer *has* ink! Ubuntu doesn't believe.)

Tags: ubuntu, printing

I have HP Photosmart 5520 and print from xubuntu 14.04.4 LTS.
Printer is fine.
I had low ink at one point in the past. With a new ink cartridge I could print several pages, then printing stops with system-config-printer still showing 'low on ink' status message.
MS Windows interprets ink levels correctly, as it uses HP's own software, I guess.
Can I get my lovely Ubuntu system to forget that ink was once low?

Comment: You'll get a better answer on Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: No answer at all from Ask Ubuntu, but thanks for suggestion @AndroidDev. hp-levels utility shows correct ink levels. system-config-printer is a Fedora / Red Hat / Ubuntu util, I believe.